# How to change AppCompatButton corner radius?

Tags: android

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/logout" />
```

Above is my button xml it have a small corner radius by default now i need to change the radius a little bit how i can change only corner radius?

Answer (score 3):

Use custom style: create the following file into your drawable folder.

button_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#9CD0E3" />
            <stroke
                android:width="7dp"
                android:color="#55BDE4" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#55BDE4"
                android:endColor="#55BDE4"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="7dp"
                android:color="#9DD0E2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

example 2 (button_style.xml): only corner radius.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="15dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="15dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then use this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchBox"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:text="@string/logout" />
```

Look at the `android:radius="3dp"` in button_style.xml.... increase the dp as much as you want..