# drawable start not working with material button

Tags: android, material-design

Here is the button :

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_choose_photo"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_camera"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/image_picker_dialog_choose_image"
    android:textAlignment="textStart" />
```

I am using material themes, so this will be inflated into a material button
drawableStart has no effect at all, however drawableEnd, bottom and top work just fine
When I make the button tag a text view, drawableStart works
It seems like a bug or maybe I am missing something ?

Edit: My app theme is as follows :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!---colors-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondary</item>

    <!--
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    -->

    <!--components-->
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/text_input_layout_style</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/bottom_sheet_dialog_theme</item>

    <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/spinner_style</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinner_style</item>

    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/toolbar_style</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/toolbar_style</item>

    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflow_button_style</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflow_button_style</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Hello, please provide more context by adding your base theme configuration.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: just use drawableLeft

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Ok, It works when using drawableLeft, but it show a warning "consider replacing android:drawableLeft with android:drawableStart to better support right to left layouts"

Comment: But still, why drawableStart is not working

Comment: I think, you should use app:icon="@drawable/ic_camera", [docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Thanks bro, It works and also changes the tint of the icon to match app theme style
Add an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should use app:icon like this:

In the layout:

```
<Button
   ...
   app:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
/>
```

It is displayed at the start, before the text label. You can change icon gravity, tint or size.

For more [information](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/)

Comment: Why would Material not simply also support `drawableStart`? Yet another piece of mental baggage every developer must carry around with them thanks to Material.

Comment: Note that tint for this is set by `app:iconTint` instead of `android:drawableTint`

Answer (score 12):

Using

```
android:drawableLeft
```

will solve the problem, but will not give you RTL(Right to left) support. If your end user uses a different language which follow RTL, then your `Button` will not support it.

Are you managing the Button's property in the Activity or Fragment, as technically speaking,

```
android:drawableStart
```

should work.

Comment: In this case we can use `android:drawableTint` or `app:drawableTint` to set icon color.

Answer (score 3):

You can change to "App compat button"

[image]

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/continuar_anonimo_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/greenPrimary"
                android:background="@drawable/corner_boton_outline"
                android:text="Continuar anonimamente"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_google_color"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
```

Comment: Doing this will remove the rounded corners, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031535/how-to-change-appcompatbutton-corner-radius along with 'android:background=""' to make the button have rounded corners.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:drawableLeft`

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/continuar_anonimo_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/greenPrimary"
                android:background="@drawable/corner_boton_outline"
                android:text="Continuar anonimamente"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"

                **android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"**
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView?authuser=2#attr_android:drawableLeft

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
```

Is the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

With the Material theme, the `android:drawableStart` or `android:drawableLeft` attribute must be replaced by `app:icon` and `app:iconGravity="start"`.

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_dialogs_24px"
    app:iconGravity="start"
    app:iconPadding="8dp"/>
```